# Scrapy doen't show each link crawled with its data in my own pattern

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
from twisted.internet import reactor
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from lxml import html

class GivenSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
#       filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        select = Selector(response)
        urls=GivenSpider()
        u=urls.start_urls
        titles = select.xpath('//a[@class="listinglink"]/text()').extract()
        print ' [*] Start crawling at %s ' % u
        for title in titles:
            print '\t %s' % title


#configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
runner = CrawlerRunner()

d = runner.crawl(GivenSpider)
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
```

the output is:

```
 [*] Start crawling at ['http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/', 'http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/'] 
     eff-bot's Daily Python URL
     O'Reilly Python Center
     Python Developer's Guide
     Social Bug
 [*] Start crawling at ['http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/', 'http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/'] 
     Core Python Programming
     Data Structures and Algorithms with Object-Oriented Design Patterns in Python
     Dive Into Python 3
     Foundations of Python Network Programming
     Free Python books
     FreeTechBooks: Python Scripting Language
     How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python
     An Introduction to Python
     Learn to Program Using Python
     Making Use of Python
     Practical Python
     Pro Python System Administration
     Programming in Python 3 (Second Edition)
     Python 2.1 Bible
     Python 3 Object Oriented Programming
     Python Language Reference Manual
     Python Programming Patterns
     Python Programming with the Java Class Libraries: A Tutorial for Building Web and Enterprise Applications with Jython
     Python: Visual QuickStart Guide
     Sams Teach Yourself Python in 24 Hours
     Text Processing in Python
     XML Processing with Python
```

But I want to print each url crawled in the right place. like so:

```
 [*] Start crawling at http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/
     eff-bot's Daily Python URL
     O'Reilly Python Center
     Python Developer's Guide
     Social Bug
 [*] Start crawling at http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/
     Core Python Programming
     Data Structures and Algorithms with Object-Oriented Design Patterns in Python
     Dive Into Python 3
     Foundations of Python Network Programming
     Free Python books
     FreeTechBooks: Python Scripting Language
     How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python
     An Introduction to Python
     Learn to Program Using Python
     Making Use of Python
     Practical Python
     Pro Python System Administration
     Programming in Python 3 (Second Edition)
     Python 2.1 Bible
     Python 3 Object Oriented Programming
     Python Language Reference Manual
     Python Programming Patterns
     Python Programming with the Java Class Libraries: A Tutorial for Building Web and Enterprise Applications with Jython
     Python: Visual QuickStart Guide
     Sams Teach Yourself Python in 24 Hours
     Text Processing in Python
     XML Processing with Python
```

How can I handle it in scrapy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This info is in `response`:

```
print ' [*] Start crawling at %s ' % response.url
```

Check the examples in [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions).